# Unable to remove folder with CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I just installed the new LibreOffice version, but it failed because it couldn't delete the program folder in "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5", so I tried removing it with the Explorer and admin CMD, didn't work. Then I opened a System command prompt with psExec -i -s cmd and tried some commands on the folder:

```
rd /s program
takeown /r /f program
icacls program
```

Every command failed with "Access denied", so how do I remove it? I know that I could just ignore the windows permission system with a Linux distribution, but that's too much effort just for removing a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the windows uninstall tool.  If for some reason you can't do that try open cmd as admin and then type `rd C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5`